# Is $m=(n+1)^2\Leftrightarrow m= n^2+2n+1$?

Tags: logic

I always assumed it was but a student asked about for $m \in N$ $m=(-n-1)^2 \Rightarrow m=n^2+2n+1$ and so suggested that $m=(n+1)^2$ was not therefore a necessary condition.
I have tried to reconcile this fact by showing that
 $m=(n+1)^2 \Leftrightarrow m= (-n-1)^2$.

Here is my attempt:

$m=(n+1)^2\Leftrightarrow m=(n+1)(n+1)\Leftrightarrow m=1\times(n+1)(n+1)\Leftrightarrow m=(-1)^2(n+1)(n+1)\Leftrightarrow m=(-1(n+1)\times-1(n+1))\Leftrightarrow m=(-1(n+1)))^2\Leftrightarrow m=(-n-1)^2$

Is this correct?

**I'm concerned that I can't go directly $m=(n+1)^2\Leftarrow m=n^2+2n+1$ as a necessary condition because both
$m=(n+1)^2\Rightarrow m=n^2+2n+1$ and $m=(-n-1)^2\Rightarrow m=n^2+2n+1$**
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Question came up when we tried to prove the sum of consecutive squares is odd.

Comment: $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n +1$ and $(-n-1)^2 = (-1)^2(n+1)^2 = (n+1)^2$. Both are the same

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what exactly it is that you are having trouble with. It looks a little bit like you are concerned that you can express the same number in different ways, specifically, that "$(-n-1)^2$" and "$(n+1)^2$" denote the same number. Is that it? If so, you are actually familiar with this: $1+1=2=3-1$.

Comment: @Jishin Noben I've highlighted my concern in the edit if that helps. Thanks

Comment: @Karl Here $m$ is positive as it is a square of a real number. So it doesn't matter here whether we're taking $n+1$ or $-n-1$. But if we take the square root of m, we should consider $\pm(n+1)$

Comment: Following the suggestions above, $\Leftrightarrow$ holds between formulas. Thus, you have to use subst property of equlity for formulas : $a=b \Rightarrow (\varphi[x/a] \Leftrightarrow \varphi[x/b])$ using the identity : $(n+1)^2=(n^2+1+2n)$ in place of $a=b$.

Comment: $(n + 1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 = (-n -1)^2$, so the conditions $m = (n+1)^2$ and $m = (-n-1)^2$ are identical and the two apparently different necessary conditions say exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing about one problem (which isn't one), but all your concern seems to look at another problem, which is one.

You think that

$$m=(n+1)^2\Leftrightarrow m= n^2+2n+1$$

is problematic, which it isn't. Because it is easy to see using binomial theorem that

$$(n+1)^2=n^2+2\times n\times 1 + 1^2 =n^2+2n+1$$

and by the transivity of the equality "=" that proves what you want to proof! The $m$ is of no real concern here, it is just one number that is said to be equal to two different experessions of the same number.

What your concerns are (correctly) about is that

$$m=(n+1)\Leftrightarrow m^2= n^2+2n+1$$

is incorrect, as $m=-n-1$ would also work. But that is not what your problem, as written, is about. Notice that $n+1$ lost the square on the left side and $m$ got it added to the right side.

Comment: The binomial theorem is a bit overkill here -- though it certainly works. (+1 for addressing the actual confusion in the question)

Comment: This really helps. I will add a full proof later as an answer for review. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of two consecutive squares is given by
$$n^2+(n+1)^2=2n^2+2n+1=2(n^2+n)+1=2k+1$$
Hence the result is odd. There is no need to even mention implications to prove this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the question to further clarify.